# Routing in cloud run: equivalent of dispatch.yaml / replacement service for cloud run

Tags: google-cloud-run

Any suggestions for an equivalent routing service for cloud-run, similar to dispatch.yaml for app engine?

We'd like the flexibility of (temporarily) sending traffic to a different service based on URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to route certain paths to certain Cloud Run services, I recommend using [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run), it integrates with Cloud Run.