# Migrate from App Engine to Cloud Run - dispatch.yaml alternative?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have an AppEngine Standard project that's been running for several years. Now I'm starting to have issues with some of AppEngine's limitations, such as no support for websockets.

I've started experimenting with Cloud Run and so far it's going well. I've created a service from the same codebase which works fine from the *.run.app URL and, using the "Domain Mappings" feature it also works on a burner domain.

The thing is, Domain Mappings is really limited and can't substitute for dispatch.yaml.

I have 3 domains (and a bunch of subdomains) that I route to various services. These routes need to change from time to time with no downtime. With dispatch.yaml I can do that easily - edit, deploy, done. Every change to Domain Mappings is a major event requiring 15 minutes to 24 hours downtime, so not an option.

It looks like Cloud Load Balancing would be a better way to go and I'd like to do some experiments but I have questions first!

1. Is there a some other feature that would fit my needs that is less complex and doesn't cost money (dispatch.yaml is free after all)?
2. If I create an experimental load balancer specifically for one domain and one cloud run service will it affect my production AppEngine services in any way? It looks like it should be OK but I don't want to risk everything going offline because I missed some configuration step. (In other words, I'm scared and I need someone to tell me I'll be OK!)

Thanks for any alternatives/advice/reassurance

Answer (score 1):

I offer the following suggestions:

1. In Cloud Run, there are various ways to serve web traffic.

- **[Mapping Custom Domains](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains)** - As you have mentioned, you already tried using Domain mappings, but the long downtime made it a bad option. I found a workaround that you can try if you still want to use it. In the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59255283/switch-a-live-domain-to-google-cloud-run-without-downtime), @ahmet alp balkan mentioned that option 1 would still have a downtime, while option 2 won't have, but it will utilize cloudflare proxying, which is an enterprise plan feature.
- **[Serve Static Assets with Cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/set-up-cdn)** - Cloud CDN utilizes an application load balancer, along with Google's global edge network to deliver content to the users.
- **[Serve Traffice from Multiple Regions](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/multiple-regions)** - Here, you need to deploy services in multiple regions so that users are routed to the nearest region. It utilizes an external application load balancer to route users.
- **[Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run)** - As mentioned by @Steren in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56604106/routing-in-cloud-run-equivalent-of-dispatch-yaml-replacement-service-for-clou), it can be used to be integrated with Cloud run if you want to route paths to cloud run services.

2. Creating a [load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview) for a specific domain and a cloud run service will not affect your App Engine service. Check out [Backend services overview](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#backends), backend service configuration determines how it connects to its backends and how the load balancer distributes traffic. These settings can be used to control how the load balancer behaves. So, you shouldn't worry about your App engine Service

Comment: Cloudflare proxying would be a great solution. I already use Cloudflare but the enterprise plan is way to expensive.

Firebase sounds like an option, although I know nothing about it!

All the others are variations on load balancing so I think I'll start there.

Serve Static Assets with Cloud CDN